# Minecraft server share port with apache

Tags: apache-http-server, port-forwarding, minecraft

Hello I have a Minecraft server in my computer. I can play with my friends when we in the same LAN. But I want to publish it to the Internet so that my friends can play with me wherever.

I already have a internet ip (let call it `12.12.12.12`) and I bought a domain name (let call it `example.com`).

The problem is that my computer is behind a firewall that I can't control. I can only use port 80 to serve a server and I already have a Apache server on port 80.

I've try to use apache vhost reverse proxy but unfortunately minecraft doesn't use http so it can't work.

I think of an idea that redirecting `minecraft.example.com:80` to `12.12.12.12:25565`(minecraft server) and `www.example.com:80` to `12.12.12.12:8000`(apache server). How can I get it?

---

my computer is ubuntu18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with non-HTTP / non-TLS protocols, because there is no way to determine what domain name the client tried to use. The requested domain name is carried *inside* the HTTP request, or inside the TLS handshake.

(You *could* achieve this easily if you had the HTTPS port 443 available, and if Minecraft used TLS for its own communications... but unfortunately it does not.)

One remaining option is to use a *custom* "reverse proxy" program, which forwards connections based on the initial packet – for example, if the client's first data begins with `GET` or another HTTP verb, then the whole connection gets forwarded to Apache; otherwise it's forwarded to Minecraft.

(It might be possible to build this with specialized load-balancer software such as HAproxy? But probably easier to write the program from scratch... Additionally, the program would need to run on the router, in order to be able to preserve real client IP addresses.)